# I created a file type and an interpreter for the file type. I want to enable the interpreter run the file type once the file type is doublr clicked

Tags: python, file, exe, pyinstaller

I created a file type called oox, I created an interpreter for the file type. I used to do all of the task python.

I compiled the source code with pyinstaller to get the exe of the interpreter, the exe works perfectly; now i want to make the program to run the file type without asking user for input, but rather; through double clicking on the oox file.

What do i need to add to the source code to perform the task?.

The first set of lines after the import statements for the interpreter are below:

```
print('Please input the .oox file:')
doc = input() #This is the oox file
```

Answer (score 0):

The normal solution is to pass the path to the file to operate on as a *command-line argument*, which can be provided non-interactively, rather than prompting the user for interactive input using the `input` function.

The `argparse` module in the standard library provides a wealth of tools for parsing command-line arguments. In a simple case like this, though, you can just use `sys.argv[1]` to get the first command-line argument as a string.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, It's working now; I found some resources that could help me. I am grateful.